# Difference between 'anyone' and 'anyone else'

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between these two sentences?

1- My mother loves me more than anyone.

2- My mother loves me more than anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

**My mother loves me more than anyone**
States that My mother loves me more than any other mother love its kid

**My mother loves me more than anyone else** states that My mother loves me more than any other kid she loves

Answer (score 0):

The sentences are quite generic, and may have more than one meaning. But given a context, their meanings become clearer.

But to analyze further, the meanings are thus:

> 1 -  Of the people who love me, no one loves me like my mother does
>
> 2 -  Out of all the people my mother loves, her love for me is the greatest

Comment: No. Technically, both sentences are ambiguous, in that they both have both meanings. The wording doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

- **My mother loves me more than anyone** means she loves me more than any person at all.
- **My mother loves me more than any one else** means she loves me more than any other person.
- The adverb *else* is used after the word *anyone* to mean *another person*
  Source; https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anyone%20else

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, both sentences are ambiguous (as pointed out by @Mr Lister already). I will pick the second sentence to demonstrate this:

> My mother loves me more than anyone else.

There are at least two possible interpretations here:

1. My mother loves me more than does anyone else.
2. My mother loves me more than she loves anyone else.

I would use "else" in both cases because the comparison is between one person and everyone else.